# Iterate through a child map in a for loop in groovy

Tags: for-loop, groovy, hashmap

Let us assume I have a map like below which contains another map (child map) within it. I like to print the child map as individual rows for each key.

```
def map =[   
  1: [
    [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York"],
    [name:"Long", age: 25, city: "New York"]
  ],  
  2: [
    [name:"Dustin", age: 29, city: "New York"],
    [name:"Bob", age: 34, city: "New York"]
  ]
]
```

Currently, I iterate through the parent map, and am able to print the names. But, that is not actually what I want. I wanted to see if I can atleast iterate through the parent map. I do not see errors so far.

```
    for(allentries in map){
    loggerApi.info("${allentries.key}: ${allentries.value.name}") // this prints [Jerry, Long] for key 1 & [Dustin, Bob] for key 2
    loggerApi.info("${allentries.key}: ${allentries.value.age}")
    loggerApi.info("${allentries.key}: ${allentries.value.city}")
    
    }
```

Can you please let me know what I should add to the above code to see individual rows like these:

```
Name Age City
Jerry 42 New York
Long 25 New York
Dustin 29 New York
Bob 34 New York
```

Appreciate.

Thank you.

Br,
Noor.

Comment: Are your values supposed to be lists of maps? You're having two expressions for each key, which wouldn't compile: `1: [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York"],[name:"Long", age: 25, city: "New York"]`

Comment: Yes, I have 2 expressions assigned against key 1. Let us call these as sub-maps. I am able to assign these sub-maps to the key 1. Now, I need to iterate through the sub-maps individually. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I am extremely sorry. The input data structure I gave was wrong. Now, I edited it. I was using the word sub map/child map to indicate the map within a map. I hope it helps now. I see Tim's reply may help me solve the problem. I will try tomorrow early morning & let you know all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got the input structure wrong in the question, and you have a list of maps inside each value in `map`, you can just iterate through them in an internal loop

```
​def map =[   
  1: [
    [name:"Jerry", age: 42, city: "New York"],
    [name:"Long", age: 25, city: "New York"]
  ],  
  2: [
    [name:"Dustin", age: 29, city: "New York"],
    [name:"Bob", age: 34, city: "New York"]
  ]
]

map.each { key, value ->
  value.each { submap ->
    println "$key $submap.name $submap.age $submap.city"
    // Or with no prefixing number:
    // println "$submap.name $submap.age $submap.city"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tim, I am sorry for the mistake in the input & thank you for the correction. I will try this piece of code tomorrow early & let you know the feedback. By the way, for now, please let me know if the word "submap" which you used in the code you gave - is it a keyword in groovy? In the sense, will groovy recognise it?

Comment: Hiya! No, that's just a variable name I used for each map in your value (which is a list of maps)

Comment: I think the requirements call for output like `"Jerry 42 New York"` but I think the code above is going to output `"1 Jerry 42 New York"`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown fixed as a commented out line 

Comment: @tim_yates - Hello Tim, can you please let me know how I can assign the keys and values  to variables, preferably in a for loop. I tried the below and get an error - map.each { key, value ->
empkey = $key
loggerApi.info("what is the key: ${empkey}")
}

Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $key for class: Script13

Comment: You just need to do `empkey = key`, not `empkey = $key`...  Not sure why you'd do it though...it's already in a variable in that loop, called `key`...  If you don't like `key`, you can change it to what you want with `map.each { empkey, value ->` for example